# Type inference in java

Tags: java, generics, types

Could you please explain why below work in a way is does.
It seems to me the java type system is weak to infer the type of R

```
public class Test {

interface Parser<A,R>{
    R parse(A a);
}

static class ResponseParser implements Parser<String,Integer>{

    public Integer parse(String s) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s) + 1;
    }
}

interface Function<A,R>{
    R with(A a);
}

public static <A,R,P extends Parser<A,R>> Function<P,R> getResult(final A res){
        return new Function<P, R>() {
            public R with(P parser) {
                return parser.parse(res);
            }
        };
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Function<Parser<String,Integer>, Integer> func = getResult("1");
    //this works
    func.with(new ResponseParser());
    // why this does not work
    getResult("1").with(new ResponseParser());
}


}
```

Comment: I just wish to understand why 'R' is not being inferred

Comment: then how come below complies ?
 Function<Parser<String,Integer>, Integer> func = getResult("1");
    //this works
    func.with(new ResponseParser());

Comment: and  getResult("1").with(new ResponseParser());  doesn't even compile

Comment: AFAIK, the compiler will check that the ResponseParser passed to with() is compatible with the return type of getResult(). So to do that, it needs to know the return type of getResult(). But it  can't, because you haven't specified any generic type for the getResult() method call, and it can't infer them since the returned value is no assigned to any variable as it is in the first example. Java won't infer the type of a method getResult() from an argument passed to the method with() called on the result of getResult().

Comment: @RealSkeptic, he doesn't use raw types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `getResult("1").with(new ResponseParser());` expression the type of `getResult("1")` sub-expression cannot be inferred correctly from context. To your opinion it should be `Function<? extends Parser<String, Integer>, Integer>`, but this subexpression knows nothing about `Integer`. In the first case you assign the result to the `Function<Parser<String,Integer>, Integer>`, so the `R = Integer` type can be resolved, but when you just call some other method, it doesn't work.

You can fix this deferring the necessity to infer the return type. Something like this:

```
interface ParserFunction<A> {
    <R> R with(Parser<A, R> a);
}

public static <A> ParserFunction<A> getResult(final A res){
        return new ParserFunction<A>() {
            public <R> R with(Parser<A, R> parser) {
                return parser.parse(res);
            }
        };
}
```

Now `getResult("1").with(new ResponseParser());` works.

Comment: Just wanted to understand why in this case it is able to infer the type...Actually, wish to understand how it is inferring type of R

Comment: @Abhishekkapoor, in the fixed code the `R` type should not be inferred for `getResult("1")`. It inferred for `with` and here it's possible as it knows that `new ResponseParser()` is the parser which returns `Integer`.

Comment: so does that mean you are deferring the inference of R, so that it will be inferred by subexpression

Comment: @Abhishekkapoor, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are only used by the compiler to ensure that you do not violate the rules for the type you specify. During run time all generics are converted to `Object` but the type safety is ensured because the compiler will notify you of any violations or type safety. To achieve this though you need to tell the compiler what try you are using and this is why generics are not inferred.

Check out erasure with java generics https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html